# Strange behavior of the network bridge

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, network-bridge

I created a network bridge (for libvirt) as follows:

```
nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname enp3s0 master br0
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.addresses ***
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.gateway ***
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.dns '***'
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.method manual
nmcli con modify br0 bridge.stp no
nmcli con up bridge-slave-enp3s0
```

After a normal reboot, the system is like this:

```
$ nmcli conn show
NAME                 UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
br0                  0e94307b-e86f-4987-ab11-178bdd9f80d9  bridge    br0
lo                   b2bac3d3-d51f-4f6c-b1aa-98ae95a8e298  loopback  lo
bridge-slave-enp3s0  85f6225c-bd8d-4cfc-a1dc-d196ea0870d5  ethernet  enp3s0
```

And after waking the system from sleep, it is like this:

```
$ nmcli conn show
NAME                 UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
br0                  0e94307b-e86f-4987-ab11-178bdd9f80d9  bridge    br0
lo                   b2bac3d3-d51f-4f6c-b1aa-98ae95a8e298  loopback  lo
enp3s0               fd23344b-3bde-4ab4-9a8a-f0dc555f589b  ethernet  enp3s0
bridge-slave-enp3s0  85f6225c-bd8d-4cfc-a1dc-d196ea0870d5  ethernet  --
```

The system once again adds the same device to the bridge. Disconnecting (from the command line or interface) removes the newly added connection and automatically connects using the original configuration, and there it is again:

```
$ nmcli conn show
NAME                 UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
br0                  0e94307b-e86f-4987-ab11-178bdd9f80d9  bridge    br0
lo                   b2bac3d3-d51f-4f6c-b1aa-98ae95a8e298  loopback  lo
bridge-slave-enp3s0  85f6225c-bd8d-4cfc-a1dc-d196ea0870d5  ethernet  enp3s0
```

In both cases the connection works properly, but a little strange some....

Operating System: Kubuntu 23.10

Comment: After each successive repetition of "sleep" - "wake up" in the bridge remains two connections - one active, the other not, and the system icon shows "no connection". The connection, however, works....